# How do you pass data from qml file in a stack view to a table in database

Tags: python, qt, qml, pyside2

There are four files; main.qml file where there is the stackview which displays the addNew.qml file as the initial item and contains two buttons the back and the next. Upon clicking the next button the texts in the text fields should be inserted into the database table customer. However, when data is inserted into the fields and the next button is clicked nothing gets inserted into the database.

addNew.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15

Item {
    Rectangle {
        id: rectangle
        color: "#5b5858"
        anchors.fill: parent

        Label {
            id: label
            x: 42
            y: 49
            width: 105
            height: 36
            color: "#ffffff"
            text: qsTr("Firstname")
            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
            verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
            font.pointSize: 14
        }

        Label {
            id: label1
            x: 42
            y: 116
            width: 105
            height: 36
            color: "#ffffff"
            text: qsTr("Lastname")
            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
            verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
            font.pointSize: 14
        }

        Label {
            id: label2
            x: 42
            y: 185
            width: 105
            height: 36
            color: "#ffffff"
            text: qsTr("Age")
            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
            verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
            font.pointSize: 14
        }

        Label {
            id: label3
            x: 42
            y: 241
            width: 105
            height: 36
            color: "#ffffff"
            text: qsTr("Sex")
            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
            verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
            font.pointSize: 14
        }

        TextInput {
            id: txtfname
            x: 203
            y: 56
            width: 149
            height: 22
            color: "#fdfdfd"
            text: qsTr("")
            font.pixelSize: 12
        }

        TextInput {
            id: txtlname
            x: 203
            y: 123
            width: 149
            height: 22
            color: "#fdfdfd"
            text: qsTr("")
            font.pixelSize: 12
        }

        TextInput {
            id: txtage
            x: 203
            y: 192
            width: 149
            height: 22
            color: "#fdfdfd"
            text: qsTr("")
            font.pixelSize: 12
        }

        RadioButton {
            id: isMale
            x: 223
            y: 247
            width: 112
            height: 40
            text: qsTr("Male")
        }

        RadioButton {
            id: isFemale
            x: 224
            y: 291
            width: 112
            height: 40
            text: qsTr("Female")
        }
    }

    Connections{
        target: backend

        function onAddPrimaryData(fname, lname, age, ismale) {
            txtfname.text = fname
            txtlname.txt = lname
            txtage.text =age
            if (isMale.checked === true){
                ismale = true
            }
            if (isFemale.checked === true){
                ismale = false
            }
        }
    }

}
```

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    property string page: "addNew.qml"
    Rectangle {
        id: rectangle
        color: "#212121"
        anchors.fill: parent

        Button {
            id: button
            x: 389
            y: 414
            text: qsTr("Back")
        }

        Button {
            id: button1
            x: 516
            y: 414
            text: qsTr("Next")
            onClicked:{
                if (page === "addNew.qml"){
                     stackView.push("addNewEmpData.qml")
                }
                backend.addNewPrimaryData
            }
        }

        StackView {
            id: stackView
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.right: parent.right
            anchors.top: parent.top
            anchors.bottom: button.top
            anchors.rightMargin: 10
            anchors.leftMargin: 10
            anchors.topMargin: 10
            anchors.bottomMargin: 10
            initialItem: Qt.resolvedUrl(page)
        }
    }
}

/*##^##
Designer {
    D{i:0;formeditorZoom:0.66}D{i:3}D{i:4}D{i:1}
}
##^##*/
```

main.py

```
import sys
import os
import mysql.connector


from PySide2.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PySide2.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine
from PySide2.QtCore import QObject, Slot, Signal

class MainWindow(QObject):
    def __init__(self):
        QObject.__init__(self)


    @Slot(str, str, int, bool)
    def addPrimaryData(self, firstName, lastName, age, isMale):
        db = mysql.connector.connect(
               host = "localhost",
               user = "root",
               passwd = "",
               database = "test"
           )
        mycursor = db.cursor(buffered =True)

        sex = 'M'

        if isMale == True:
            sex = 'M'
        else:
            sex = 'F'

        mycursor.execute("INSERT INTO customer VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s", (firstName, lastName, age, sex ))



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()

    #Get Context
    main = MainWindow()
    engine.rootContext().setContextProperty("backend", main)
    engine.load(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "main.qml"))

    if not engine.rootObjects():
        sys.exit(-1)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: what is `addNewPrimaryData`?

Comment: addNewPrimaryData is a function that will be executed when the next button is clicked

Comment: 1) where is it defined? in python the only function exposed to QML is addPrimaryData(different to addNewPrimaryData), 2) A function is invoked using "()"

Comment: so it is a typo. it is supposed to be addPrimaryData

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to list some errors:

- Using Connections is used to listen to signals from a QObject, not to invoke slots.
- addNewPrimaryData is not defined.
- The code `page === "addNew.qml"` will always be true.

The logic is that create a method on the page "addNew.qml" and invoke it when the button is pressed, the item can be obtained through the currentItem property. It is also good to put a name or identifier as property of the root of each page to identify them.

**addNew.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15

Item {
    readonly property string identifier: "addNew"
    Rectangle {
        id: rectangle
        color: "#5b5858"
        anchors.fill: parent

        Label {
            id: label

            x: 42
            y: 49
            width: 105
            height: 36
            color: "#ffffff"
            text: qsTr("Firstname")
            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
            verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
            font.pointSize: 14
        }

        Label {
            id: label1
            x: 42
            y: 116
            width: 105
            height: 36
            color: "#ffffff"
            text: qsTr("Lastname")
            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
            verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
            font.pointSize: 14
        }

        Label {
            id: label2
            x: 42
            y: 185
            width: 105
            height: 36
            color: "#ffffff"
            text: qsTr("Age")
            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
            verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
            font.pointSize: 14
        }

        Label {
            id: label3
            x: 42
            y: 241
            width: 105
            height: 36
            color: "#ffffff"
            text: qsTr("Sex")
            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
            verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
            font.pointSize: 14
        }

        TextInput {
            id: txtfname
            x: 203
            y: 56
            width: 149
            height: 22
            color: "#fdfdfd"
            text: qsTr("")
            font.pixelSize: 12
        }

        TextInput {
            id: txtlname
            x: 203
            y: 123
            width: 149
            height: 22
            color: "#fdfdfd"
            text: qsTr("")
            font.pixelSize: 12
        }

        TextInput {
            id: txtage
            x: 203
            y: 192
            width: 149
            height: 22
            color: "#fdfdfd"
            text: qsTr("")
            font.pixelSize: 12
        }

        RadioButton {
            id: isMale
            x: 223
            y: 247
            width: 112
            height: 40
            checked: true
            text: qsTr("Male")
        }

        RadioButton {
            id: isFemale
            x: 224
            y: 291
            width: 112
            height: 40
            text: qsTr("Female")
        }
    }
    function save() {
        var ismale = true;
        if (isMale.checked)
            ismale = true;
        if (isFemale.checked)
            ismale = false;
        backend.addPrimaryData(txtfname.text, txtlname.text, parseInt(txtage.text), ismale)
    }
}
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Rectangle {
        id: rectangle

        color: "#212121"
        anchors.fill: parent

        Button {
            id: button

            x: 389
            y: 414
            text: qsTr("Back")
            onClicked: {
                if (stackView.depth > 0)
                    stackView.pop();

            }
        }

        Button {
            id: button1

            x: 516
            y: 414
            text: qsTr("Next")
            onClicked: {
                if (stackView.currentItem.identifier === "addNew") {
                    stackView.currentItem.save();
                    stackView.push("addNewEmpData.qml");
                }
            }
        }

        StackView {
            id: stackView

            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.right: parent.right
            anchors.top: parent.top
            anchors.bottom: button.top
            anchors.rightMargin: 10
            anchors.leftMargin: 10
            anchors.topMargin: 10
            anchors.bottomMargin: 10
            initialItem: Qt.resolvedUrl("addNew.qml")
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: In the main.qml file you used currentItem.save() without defining save in the main.qml. How is that possible

Comment: @Richie_Eloh What is `stackView.currentItem`?

Comment: I did not use it in my code but i want to understand what exactly its doing how its being used

Comment: @Richie_Eloh Please read the docs: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-stackview.html#currentItem-prop

Comment: @ellyanesc After running the code There is no error but nothing gets inserted in the database either

Comment: @Richie_Eloh add `db.commit()` after `mycursor.execute()`